# How to create HTML 5 project in Aptana Studio?

Tags: html, aptana

I installed Aptana Studio 3 on my windows machine.

I created new WEB Project but when I expand my Proj folder I can see only "Connection" tab. Nothing else. What is the prob? what should I do to get all the files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Forgive me if the following is what you already did but I was not certain what steps you took from your question/post ... I'm going through the standard steps for creating an HTML 5 Web Project with the Boilerplate templates:

1. Open Aptana ( duh :) )
2. File -> New -> Web Project
3. Provide a Project Name and select your directory if you don't want the default used
4. Press Next
5. Select the checkbox for 'Create the project using one of the templates'
6. Select the HTML5 Boilerplate (use the cached one - I can never get the other, networked one to work)
7. Select Finish

You should now see the new project and all its default files in your App Explorer view in Aptana.

If you followed those steps but it still fails, I would file a bug (or, at the least, check the existing issues with Aptana) at:
http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD (bugs)

Comment: Have you tried using the network download option with git installed?

Comment: Ya I did the above thing, but couldn't find any default files & folders